# making sure the polymer build process doesn't mess with a dependency of my element

Tags: unity-game-engine, polymer, polymer-2.x, unity-webgl

I have built a custom element/web component to load and display Unity generated WebGL content.  The web component imports the UnityLoader.js module - and works fine when used within an app served with 'polymer serve'.

However, when I build an app that uses my web component via the Polymer-CLI build process, no errors are given, but when I access a page using my component I always end up with an error from within UnityLoader.js:

```
"ReferenceError: BabelHelpers is not defined"
```

If I create the element directly within my app (in other words it is no longer managed by bower) then I can exclude the minification and compilation steps within the build section of my application's polymer.json file and the built version of the app works fine.

```
  "builds": [
{
  "preset": "es5-bundled",
  "js": {
    "compile": {"exclude": ["content/**/*","UnityLoader.js"]},
    "minify": {"exclude": ["content/**/*","UnityLoader.js"]}
    },
    "html": {
      "minify": {"exclude": ["content/**/*"]}
    }
}
]
```

I've looked at my application's polymer.json file and I can see that the extraDependecies node contains some dependencies that other web components have placed there:

```
"extraDependencies": [
  "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*.js",
  "!bower_components/webcomponentsjs/gulpfile.js",
  "manifest.json",
  "bower_components/plastic-image/intersection-observer.js",
  "bower_components/ua-parser-js/dist/ua-parser.min.js"
  ],
```

I have UnityLoader.js within the extraDependencies of the element's polymer.json but that isn't getting cascaded up to an application that imports/consumes the element - which I guess must be possible as plastic-image and ua-parser-js have done it (I've looked at their bower_components folders and nothing seems obvious - other than the latter is installed as a dependency of the former).

Any ideas on how I can make sure that the UnityLoader.js that my web component uses is not compiled or minified during the build process of an application that consumes it?

Comment: to add - the UnityLoader.js is being imported via <script src="UnityLoader.js"></script> within a separate file called UntyLoader.html   - rather than direct import in my component.

Comment: it seems to be only related to ES5 builds - it works fine with ES6.  Also, I just tried a simple experiment with Polymer-cli 1.7 (polymer 3) and the PWA starter kit. Same issue with the UnityLoader.js in an ES5 Bundled build (even when included directly in the app) - "babelHelpers is not defined"

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue with `firebase-auth.js` when making an ES5 build using `polymer-cli 1.7.0`. There might be a problem when compiling/minifying specific files. I had to roll back to `1.6.0` using `npm install -g polymer-cli@1.6.0` to fix the problem.

Comment: This started when I was on 1.6.0 Alejandro - but I'll give your suggestion a try soon and let you know how that goes.